# Computing path with highest score in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, directed-graph

I have a directed graph where each node has a score. Starting from a node, I need to find the highest score that can be achieved by following a path. Not all nodes can be final nodes. Also it is possible to revisit a node, but only the first visit counts for the score. How can I compute the highest achievable score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you may find a [**strongly connected components**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of the graph. Then you may build a **condensation** of the graph.

[image: [graph_condensation]]

Each vertex in condensation may have a score equal to the sum of the scores of vertices in initial graph.

[image: scores]

*Blue numbers show the score of each vertex in initial graph. Yellow - in graph condensation.*

Also mark some of the vertices of the condensation as terminal if they contain a final node. You will also have a mapping of each graph vertex to a vertex in condensation.

The notion of connected component is important because if you find yourself in one vertex of a component you may easily visit all the other vertices of the component to maximise the score. You are free to revisit each vertex any number of times.

Condensation itself is a **directed acyclic graph**. You can now traverse a condensation graph with depth first search maintaining the function

**F<sub>v</sub> = 0** - if V does not have reachable termination vertex (*bottom-right vertex on the picture below*)

**F<sub>v</sub> = MAX<sub>i</sub>(F<sub>child<sub>v,i</sub></sub>) + score<sub>v</sub>** - otherwise

[image: F_calculated]

*Red circles show what vertices in initial graph and condensation considered terminal.*
*Numbers in green show what F-value each vertex in condensation graph has.*

The answer to your problem would be F-value of the vertex in condensation that corresponds to a starting vertex in initial graph. Overall time complexity would be O(N + M) wher N is a number of vertices and M - a number of edges in initial graph.